# Wired unmanaged in Ubuntu 19.04 server

Tags: wired

I installed Ubuntu 19.04 server and then installed the graphic interface because I am no expert and I need it. My wired Internet connection is working well, but when I want to set a static IP I don't know how to do it, since in my network settings doesn't appear any wired connection, and the connection icon says "wired unmanaged".

I've tried the following:
- Edited /etc/network/interfaces and changed managed to true. Then restarted the Network Manager but nothing happened
- Then, sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf . Didn't work either
- In the same file, tried to set unmanaged devices to none. Didn't work.

Now I don't know what else I could try. Any advice, please?

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/network/interfaces` is not used since 18.04 when Ubuntu switched to netplan. You can find netplan configuration under /etc/netplan/

Check the file which is in that directory, you will find your network interfaces there.

If you want netplan to use NetworkManager, edit the file to look like this

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Then apply new config with `sudo netplan apply`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did what you suggested and it didn't work for me. Actually, it was worse than the initial problem, because after editing /etc/netplan/50-cloud-ini.yaml my internet connection stopped working. What I did then was to write it back to its initial condition and restart the computer, and suddenly the connection was working perfectly and I don't have the "wired unmanaged" icon any more.